# How to run multiple shell scripts in parallel?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm running shell scripts in parallel like below. Both scripts return code is ZERO but one of them is actually returning 2.  Any idea what could be the issue. Based on return code i decide whether its success/fail

```
./shellscript1.sh & pid1=$!
ReturnCode=$?

./shellscript2.sh & pid2=$!
checkFlagReturnCode=$?


wait $pid1
wait $pid2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot capture the return code of a background process which has not finished.  You can get the return codes from `wait` not from `$?`.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on how to get the return codes from wait

Answer (score 1):

You can look to [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). Their [tutorial](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) has lots of examples.